# Unable to change font color while typing in Contact Form 7 for Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form

Website in question: https://snapsbylia.com/contact-form-7/

I'm trying to change the color of text while I'm typing to white instead of black.

I found a code that should change the color of text while typing in the form to white, but it does nothing. I think it's something to do with the theme but I don't have enough technical knowledge to figure it out.

I'm using the theme customize CSS code below:

textarea:focus, input:focus {     color: #fff; }

Would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly who is setting the color for those inputs. You'll see that the specificity of your setting is below what is being used. Try as an experiment to set your CSS with a !important. You should find that overrides those settings. However, I don't recommend that you stick with important for long! It may override thing you don't want overridden. Instead, find the selector that is actually being used and use that - it should make your white be selected then.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to change color on focus.

```
input[type="color"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="month"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="range"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="week"]:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus{color: #fff;}
```

Comment: I tried the code but it did not work. How do I check if the theme is restricting me to change the color?

Comment: Theme is not restricting to change color. May be there are other overwrite your color with css. Add "!important" in css. {color: #fff !important;}